# How to use Struct with Bit Fields

Tags: c, struct

I am using a file shared between multiple programmers which has this struct:

```
typedef struct _APPLE{
   ULONG appleID;
   struct{
       ULONG isBig: 1;
       ULONG isRed: 1;
       ULONG isFresh: 1;
       ULONG isGood: 1;
       ULONG bReserved: 28;
   };
}APPLE;
```

As the file is shared I cant edit it.I want to use this APPLE struct in my code and want to provide values to each of its members. How can I do this?

Comment: What is the issue you are facing in creating its instances? Is there any problem in doing `Apple a; a.isBig=0;`?

Comment: I can do that. but when i do this a.isBig=0; does the memory is shared like a union here or i can give values for each of the member separately?

Comment: No. Its your own object created.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you can't have anonymous nested structures in standard C, it's an extension used by some compilers.

So you have to name your bit-field structure:

```
typedef struct _APPLE{
   ULONG appleID;
   struct{
       ULONG isBig: 1;
       ULONG isRed: 1;
       ULONG isFresh: 1;
       ULONG isGood: 1;
       ULONG bReserved: 28;
   } flags;
}APPLE;
```

Then just use normal dot-notation to access the fields:

```
APPLE apple;
apple.appleID = 5;
apple.flags.isBig = 1;
apple.flags.isRed = 0;
```

---

And while multiple members of a bit-field may share the same `int`, they are still separate from each other. So changing one member of a bit-field will not change any other.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2012, i think its supported here. becoz other programmers are using it.

Answer (score 0):

According to **ISO/IEC 9899:2011**, section **§6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers**

`An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bitfield. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified.`